# CoreText adds extra space to the las line of every paragraph

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-text, nsattributedstring

I am displaying this string (notice the breaks):

```
CONSEJO
NACIONAL
PARA LA
CULTURA
Y LAS ARTES
```

I have configured the NSAttributedString to have a line height constant to 26 points using the code suggested by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#qa/qa1698/_index.html):

```
CGFloat lineSpacing = 26;
CTTextAlignment theAlignment = kCTLeftTextAlignment;

CTParagraphStyleSetting theSettings[3] = 
{
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight, sizeof(CGFloat), &lineSpacing},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight, sizeof(CGFloat), &lineSpacing},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &theAlignment },
};
```

But there is extra space on the last line:

[image]

If I manually add SPACES between the words I get the expected result, so when printing:

```
CONSEJO            NACIONAL                    PARA LA                                                                CULTURA                                                         Y LAS ARTES
```

It shows this (Notice there is no extra spacing on the last line):

[image]

This is not a sustainable solution as I dont want to manually have to change all the strings to add spaces based on the frame size.

I have been testing for months and I have not been able to solve this, the last line always gets more space.

I have also experimented with "\r" to see if this got different results, but it still adds extra space, displaying:

```
Consejo\rNacional\rpara la\rCultura\ry las Artes
```

Produced:

[Left using \r]                        [Right using SPACEs]

[image]

[Here all blue blocks are the same size]

[image]

So there is less space but there is still more than there should be.

CoreText should be able to handle a simple string like this.

Adding spaces is jut not good enough (for several reasons), there has to be a way to get this under control.

What do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the images, but I think you have run into the same problem I just met not long ago, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858879/space-between-the-last-2-lines-of-a-paragraph-is-larger).

You may use `CTTypesetter` and `CTTypesetterSuggestClusterBreak` to handle line breaks manually. I use font size as height of a line, I add linespacing when drawing lines manually, and it works fine.