# kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing not respected for first line of a CTFrame

Tags: ios, core-text

We have an app that is dependent heavily on kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing to manage spacing between paragraphs, which can vary throughout a body of text. For editing performance, we implemented our main Core Text view as a collection of CTFrames that are drawn/redrawn when appropriate.

We've found that if a paragraph uses a nonzero kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing as one of its CTParagraphStyleSettings attributes, this paragraph spacing is ignored if that paragraph is the first item in a CTFrame, even if there is a another paragraph preceding it in the text fed to the framesetter.

I suppose this behavior makes sense if you're drawing to a PDF intended to be printed, but given that we're trying to present our text a a single, scrollable and contiguous block of text, it is giving us problems. Is there any way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 6):

If you can't change the behavior with a `CTParagraphStyleSetting`, I think it's a bug, or Apple thinks that behavior makes sense. Anyway, to get the result that you desire, I think the best way is to use `CTTypesetter` and handle *lineSpacing* and *paragraphSpacing* yourself. I think the `CTFrame` implementation is quite buggy, as I just run into [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858879/space-between-the-last-2-lines-of-a-paragraph-is-larger) not long ago.

For rolling your own solution, you will need `CTTypesetterSuggestClusterBreak` or `CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreak` to calculate char count of each line. Line height can be the font size, and you add lineSpacing when drawing each line. When you encounter a newline(\n) character, add paragraphSpacing before drawing next line.

With `CTTypesetter`, things are more controllable, of course, it also adds some difficulties since you have to handle line breaks and indentation. But this is the only way I can think of to get a more desired result.

Good luck.